# Where clause does not contain a mandatory equality on all key attributes DynamoDB while delteing

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

DELETE FROM "someTableNAme" WHERE "userId" = 'someid'

Help needed. I am writing query as described in docs AWS.

Comment: my table have one PK and one sort key
SELECT userId FROM "{table_name}" WHERE Attribute between {timestamp} and {now_timestamp}
this is working for me

Comment: you must select a single item when deleting, so you must have an equality check on both the PK and sort key.

Comment: @RossWilliams can you please explain it more by writing the query for deletion  of a record
Thanks!!

Comment: there are two PK userid and userRegion is this because of two PK

Comment: See the PartiQL for DynamoDB delete documentation [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/SQLtoNoSQL.DeleteData.html).

Comment: you only have 1 pk and 1 sk. DynamoDB does not allow 2 pks. DELETE FROM "someTableNAme" WHERE "userid" = 'some_pk_value' AND "userRegion" = 'some_sk_value'

Comment: i have tried with giving one Pk userId 
DELETE FROM "tableNAme" WHERE "userId" = 'userId'

it not deleting  the recored

Answer (score 5):

If you look at the [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/SQLtoNoSQL.DeleteData.html)

> Note: You can only delete one item at a time. You cannot issue a single
> DynamoDB PartiQL statement that deletes multiple items.

The syntax is

> DELETE FROM table WHERE condition [RETURNING returnvalues]

and furthermore

> condition (Required) The selection criteria for the item to be
> deleted; this condition must resolve to a single primary key value.

Comment: I assume the same applies to `update`. The answer shortly, do not use `DynamoDB`. Why should I go one by one or write code every time I want to batch update?